# Animate image randomly size continously

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

The last topic about random moving is answered. But one of my question still not answered yet. About how to create random image size like this : http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishIETank/

So what i need? Math.random and for? Please suggest :)

Here's what i've work : http://jsfiddle.net/t9tvnvot/1/

```
function track(circle, horizontal,vertical,randomly) {
(....)
randomly[0] = Math.random * (circleX + Math.cos(length) * radius); //when i put this, the animation go crazy move
randomly[1] = Math.random * (circleX + Math.sin(length) * radius); //
}
```

Help & teach me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is prety simple....

Try changing Math.random to Math.random() and it should work...

```
function track(circle, horizontal,vertical,randomly) {
(....)
randomly[0] = Math.random() * (circleX + Math.cos(length) * radius); 
randomly[1] = Math.random() * (circleX + Math.sin(length) * radius);
}
```

Here is the edited code from the fiddle (this code generate a new position for the butterfly every time, can be far away):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var circleX = 200;
var circleY = 200; 
var radius = 150;
var length = 0;

var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var speed = 0.1;

function track(circle, horizontal,vertical) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.strokeRect(5, 5, 490, 490);
//circle track move
circle[0] = Math.random() * (circleX + Math.cos(length) * radius); 
circle[1] = Math.random() * (circleY + Math.sin(length) * radius);


length += speed;

context.beginPath();
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://es.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211766513.png";
context.drawImage(img, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2], circle[3]);
context.fill();

}
setInterval(function () {
track
([setX, setY, 50, 50], [setX, setY, 50, 50], [setX,setY, 50, 50]);}, 300);
```

See also that i increase the time of the interval funtion so it does look so messy...

This is another example but this code the butterfly only appears in the vecinity of the previous position so it doesn seem to desapear:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var length = 0;
var x = 250;
var y = 250;

var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var speed = 0.1;

function track(circle, horizontal, vertical) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.strokeRect(5, 5, 490, 490);
//movement
if (x >= 0) {
    if (x <= 450) {
        if (y >= 0) {
            if (y <= 450) {
                if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 0) {
                    x = x + Math.random() + 15;
                }
                if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 2) {
                    y = y + Math.random() + 15;
                }
                if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 1) {
                    x = x - Math.random() - 15;

                }
                if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 3) {
                    y = y - Math.random() - 15;

                }
                if (x < 0) {
                    x = 0;
                }
                if (y < 0) {
                    y = 0;
                }
                if (x > 450) {
                    x = 450;
                }
                if (y > 450) {
                    y = 450;
                }
                circle[0] = x;
                circle[1] = y;

                length += speed;

                context.beginPath();
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = "http://es.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211766513.png";
                context.drawImage(img, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2], circle[3]);
                context.fill();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
setInterval(function () {
    track([setX, setY, 50, 50], [setX, setY, 500, 500], [setX, setY, 50, 50]);
}, 30);
```

According to your comment you want the butterfly to change also size,
here is the new code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var length = 0;
var x = 250;
var y = 250;
var z = 50;

var setX = 0;
var setY = 0;
var speed = 0.1;

function track(circle, horizontal, vertical) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.strokeRect(5, 5, 490, 490);
//movement
if (x >= 0) {
if (x <= 450) {
    if (y >= 0) {
        if (y <= 450) {
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 0) {
                x = x + Math.random() + 15;
                z = z-15;
            }
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 2) {
                y = y + Math.random() + 15;
                z = z-15;
            }
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 1) {
                x = x - Math.random() - 15;
                z = z+15;

            }
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) == 3) {
                y = y - Math.random() - 15;
                z = z+10;

            }
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            }
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            }
            if (x > 450) {
                x = 450;
            }
            if (y > 450) {
                y = 450;
            }
            if (z<20){
                z=20;
            }
            if (z>100){
                z=100;
            }

            circle[0] = x;
            circle[1] = y;
            circle[3] = z;
            circle[2] = z;

            length += speed;

            context.beginPath();
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "http://es.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211766513.png";
            context.drawImage(img, circle[0], circle[1], circle[2], circle[3]);
            context.fill();
        }
    }
}
}
}
setInterval(function () {
    track([setX, setY, 50, 50], [setX, setY, 500, 500], [setX, setY, 50, 50]);
}, 60);
```

I just added the math.random with upper(100) and lower limit(20) to the circle[3] and circle[2].

Hope it helps...

Comment: Oh haha that i need is only Math.random(). Thank you very much, it helped me alot :). And how to change size of my image like this http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishIETank/ ? I need to put Math.random()? or there's a different ways?

Comment: Math.random() only not work for me to change my image size like the example. What else i need for?